How to create composite unique index in Mysql
I have table like
CREATE TABLE inconsistent_objects  (
  id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  object_id varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL  DEFAULT '' ,
  inconsistent_object_id varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL  DEFAULT '' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

How to make the second request fail? I need to block the creation of non-unique pairs

INSERT INTO eapoorg.inconsistent_fees (fee_id, inconsistent_fee_id) VALUES ('001', '002');
INSERT INTO eapoorg.inconsistent_fees (fee_id, inconsistent_fee_id) VALUES ('002', '001');

I tried to create unique index, but it didnt help
ALTER TABLE inconsistent_objects ADD UNIQUE KEY uidx (object_id, inconsistent_object_id);

Unique functional index will help. ALTER TABLE inconsistent_objects ADD UNIQUE KEY uidx ((LEAST(object_id, inconsistent_object_id), GREATEST((object_id, inconsistent_object_id)));. The columns must have the same charset/collation, if not then specify them explicitly.
